# How to instantiate the costmap

Tags: navigation, costmap, global-costmap, local-costmap, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do have a problem to instantiate the costmap in my c++ code.
I want to instantiate it to work with the resulting costmap object to obtain FREESPACE, UNKNOWN and OBSTACLE. But all I get is a costmap returning no obstacle, no inflated_obstacles, no freespace, just unknown.

This is what I preveiously start:

- turtlebot_minimal.launch
- gmapping.launch

My gmapping works fine and also the configuration of some parameter had succeeded.

THIS IS EXACTLY THE COSTMAP I WANT TO HAVE AS INSTANTIATED COSTMAP IN MY CODE !!!!

Here is my code:

```
costmap2d = new costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS("costmap", tf);
costmap2d->start();
```

This creates a costmap under /costmap which is not even close to the costmap created by /move_base.

Launchfile:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="simple_navigation" type="simple_navigation" name="simple_navigation" output="screen">
<rosparam file="$(find simple_navigation)/param/turtlebot_local_costmap.yaml" command="load" ns="costmap" />
</node>
</launch>
```

turtlebot_local_costmap.yaml:

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: /odom
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   map_topic: map
   map_type: costmap
   height: 4
   width: 4
   max_obstacle_height: 0.6
   max_obstacle_range: 2.5
   obstacle_range: 4.0
   publish_frequency: 2.0
   update_frequency: 2.0
   publish_voxel_map: false
   raytrace_range: 4.0
   resolution: 0.01
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   track_unknown_space: true
   unknown_cost_value: 255
   transform_tolerance: 2.0
   robot_radius: 0.18
   inflation_radius: 0.50

   observation_sources: scan
   scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
   bump: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud, marking: true, clearing: false}
```

So this configuration is the same as I use for tuning the parameters for gmapping.

---

UPDATE

Ok I just found my mistake ... I entered a namespace in my launch file which was not correlating with my .yaml file! So now I just removed the namespace and entered the costmap's name (local_costmap:)at the beginning of the .yaml file before I set all parameters!

Now the costmap is correct and published. I use two yaml files for the local_costmap (as above) but also for the global_costmap.
Here is the configuration for the global_costmap:

```
global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   map_topic: map
   map_type: costmap
   height: 10
   width: 10
   max_obstacle_height: 0.6
   max_obstacle_range: 2.5
   obstacle_range: 4.0
   publish_frequency: 1.0
   update_frequency: 1.0
   publish_voxel_map: false
   raytrace_range: 4.0
   resolution: 0.01
   static_map: true
   rolling_window: false
   track_unknown_space: true
   unknown_cost_value: 255
   transform_tolerance: 2.0
   robot_radius: 0.18
   inflation_radius: 0.50

   observation_sources: scan
   scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
   bump: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud, marking: true, clearing: false}
```

**But now the map from gmapping is changing but the overlying costmap does not change, corresponding to changes in laserscan or map!?**

I really appreciate every hint. Thanks

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119491/how-to-instantiate-the-costmap/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved! Have a look at this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/120756/costmaps-observation-buffer-has-not-been-updated/

---

Originally posted by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) with karma: 205 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0